# Where do I locate my Skyrim 'Saves' folder while using PlayOnLinux?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, wine

I need help in finding this Saves folder in Skyrim. I'm using PlayOnLinux (Wine, but made easier, I guess?) and have searched through every file I could find but I can't locate it.

Comment: Skyrim isn't supported by linux

Comment: @Aequitas That's what PlayOnLinux is for.

Comment: @JohntheGreen I know that but just coz a hack exists doesn't mean it won't come with problems. The fact that he said he had "searched through every file" indicates that it may not save properly. Though his answer shows that he didn't actually search "every file" initially.

Comment: @Aequitas My point is if he's using PlayOnLinux, I'm fairly certain he knows whether the game is supported or not :p

Comment: In the PlayOnLinux application itself, you can right-click on a shortcut and click "Open virtual drive" (or something like that, I can't confirm right now). That should bring you to the equivalent of C:\ for that application, and you can find the Documents folder from there.

Answer (score 2):

PlayOnLinux is just a user-friendly GUI for Wine, a free implementation of Windows on Unix. When you install a game, it creates a virtual drive, which default location is `$HOME/PlayOnLinux' s virtual drives/<name of the game>`.

In that virtual drive, **the folder "drive_c" is just like "C:\" on Windows.**

So Skyrim save files are in `drive_c/users/<username>/My Documents/My Games/Skyrim/Saves`.

Answer (score 0):

found them:

`/home/octo/PlayOnLinux's virtual drives/Skyrim/drive_c/users/octo/My Documents/My Games/Skyrim/Saves`

Comment: if you have found a solution, please accept one of the answers, by clicking on the tick next to them.